# Вывод pdf документа на страницу(WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

пишу проект на WPF(C#), и встал вопрос: как вывести страницу pdf документа в окне, при этом не должно быть никаких кнопок для редактирования, печати, только чтение самой страницы.Я новичёк, поэтому прошу подробную инструкцию, и, если можно, на русском). Для Windows 7.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий и очень похож на "сделайте всё  за меня".

Comment: Описана конкретная проблема, к которой я хочу найти решение. Что не так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Windows 10

Можно использовать API UWP ([Windows.Data.Pdf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.pdf)). Для его использования необходим добавить ссылки на:

- библиотеку метаданных UWP, путь к которой имеет вид `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\(версия)\Windows.winmd` (для добавления ссылки на нее в диалоговом окне выбора библиотеки необходимо изменить фильтр на "Все файлы");
- сборку System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll`).

Тогда код для отображения страницы PDF-документа в WPF будет выглядеть так:

XAML

```xml
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="600" >

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="grid" >
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="20,20,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="40,100,40,40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="img"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Windows.Data.Pdf;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }        

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(@"C:\files\document.pdf");
            PdfDocument pdf = await PdfDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);
            PdfPage page = pdf.GetPage(0);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();

            using (var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                await page.RenderToStreamAsync(stream);

                image.BeginInit();
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.StreamSource = stream.AsStream();
                image.EndInit();
            }
            img.Source = image;      
        }
    }    
}
```

Источник: [Lander Verhack. Creating a PDF Viewer in WPF using Windows 10 APIs](https://blogs.u2u.be/lander/post/2018/01/23/Creating-a-PDF-Viewer-in-WPF-using-Windows-10-APIs)

## Предыдущие версии Windows

Использовать какую-либо стороннюю библиотеку, например:

- [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io) - аналог WebBrowser, который поддерживает также отображение PDF
- [ActiveX-элемент Adobe Reader](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380019/Using-Adobe-Reader-in-a-WPF-app)

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужен для Windows 7. Согласен, мой косяк что сразу не указал, прошу прощения)

Comment: @РишатХусаинов Используйте сторонние компоненты, например CefSharp (https://cefsharp.github.io/) или Adobe Reader ActiveX (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380019/Using-Adobe-Reader-in-a-WPF-app)

Comment: Не могли бы подсказать, там при создании User Control(Adobe Reader ActiveX) как вызвать toolbox. В статье сказано что надо нажимать Ctrl+W,X, но это сочетание не работает

Comment: @РишатХусаинов "Вид - Панель элементов" в меню студии

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы единственный кто помог новичку, а не просто отметил вопрос как общий)